# Upload a product image using PrestaShop Web-service with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to upload a Product image using the PrestaShop Web-service.

**It is always returning the same error:**

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <errors>
      <error>
        <code><![CDATA[66]]></code>
        <message><![CDATA[Unable to save this image]]></message>
      </error>
    </errors>
  </prestashop>
```

**My current code looks like this:**

```js
const url = this.options.url 
    + '/api/images/products/' 
    + piezaSchema.querySelector('product>id').childNodes[0].nodeValue
    + '?ws_key='
    + this.options.api;

const file = require('fs').readFileSync(require('path')
        .resolve(this.options.ruta 
            + '/images/'
            + image.getAttribute('fichero')));

const resp = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'image=' + file,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

I've tried with different encoding options, sending as `'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'`, etc.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This error is triggered by the `writePostedImageOnDisk()` method in `/classes/webservice/WebserviceSpecificManagementImages.php`.

**Usually it can be due to:**

- Lack of permissions on your PHP `/tmp` folder and/or `_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_`
- `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] being empty`
- Some issues with the `customized_data` table (in case this image is attached to a customized product)

**This works for me (using PHP, not Node.js though):**

```
<?php

include(__DIR__.'/config/config.inc.php');

/* Connect to the PrestaShop Web-service */
define('PS_SHOP_URL', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'YOURWSKEY');

/* Local path to the image to upload */
$image_path = './test.png'; // Can  either be JPEG, PNG, etc.

/* Image upload */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, PS_SHOP_URL.'/api/images/products/1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => curl_file_create($image_path)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($response).'</pre>'; // Should echo '1'
curl_close($ch);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to fix by sending the image as if it were uploaded by a form:

```
async uploadImage(fichero, url) {

    const form = new FormData();

    const filePath = require('path').resolve(this.options.ruta + '/images/' + fichero);

    const file = new File([await fetch(filePath).then(r => r.blob())], fichero, {type: 'image/jpeg'});

    form.append('image', file);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
    };

    fetch(url, options);

}
```